# Concrete Mathematics: Josephus Problem for $J(n) = n/2$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

On page 25 of the second edition I am at the section revisiting the initial guess of a closed form solution for the Josephus Problem. This initial, and incorrect, guess was that the solution is $n/2$. To lead us into this renewed discussion the book says:

> Let's return briefly to our first guess, that $J(n) = n/2$ when $n$ is even. This is obviously not true in general, but we can now determine exactly when it *is* true

To find when this is true they substitute in the closed form solution and $2^m +l$ for the $n$ it represents. Then rearrange to find $l$ i.e.

$$J(n)=n/2$$
$$2l+1=(2^m+l)/2$$
$$l=\frac{(2^m-2)}{3}$$

If the number $l=\frac{(2^m-2)}{3}$ is an integer then $n=2^m+l$ will be a solution **because $l$ will be less than $2^m$**

This implies, by my reading, that $l$ is sometimes greater than $2^m$. Isn't $l$ *always* less than $2^m$? If $l$ were greater than $2^m$ then we would be going to the next power of two "block"? (As described on page 23 in the table of small values given by the recurrence)

Comment: You should maybe/probably have added a little more context to make it simpler for readers to follow, but I do understand that you could not have cited the entire chapter here.

Comment: Fair enough, I have attempted to set the scene more clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that $l$ was originally defined as the remainder after removing the most significant bit $2^m$ from the number $n$, hence originally $l<2^m$.

BUT at this point the claim is that the formula:
$$
l:=\frac{2^m-2}3\tag{$\varphi$}
$$
will produce numbers of the form $n=2^m+l$ that solve $J(n)=n/2$. So here $l$ is no longer defined as the remainder, but from formula $(\varphi)$ given above. Hence we need to note that it works correctly for it to have any relevance to the problem ie. it can be used to build a number $n=2^m+l$ having $2^m$ as its most significant bit and $l$ as its remainder.

Suppose formula $(\varphi)$ above could produce $l>2^m$. Then what would we have achieved in relation to the actual problem? Then $2^m$ would NOT be $n$'s most significant bit and $l$ would NOT be the relevant remainder used in the Josephus formula.

I hope this is clear and helps!

Comment: It certainly does, thanks for clarifying!